# Use arrays, lists, or else for thousands of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I have the following method that gets direcory names:

```
    private List<String> getListOfDirectories(String rootDirectoryPath) {

        List<String> listOfDirectories = new ArrayList<>();

        File directory = new File(rootDirectoryPath);
        File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                listOfDirectories.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
        }

        return listOfDirectories;
    }
```

I am temporarily storing (not sure if storing is the proper terminology) these directory names in a List. If there are 50000 directory names, is the List the right choice? Is it memory efficient, and can it handle 50000 or more strings?

**Edit: I am developing an app that searches local directory for html files and parses those html files.**

Comment: No matter what way you cut it, your program is going to be storing 50,000 strings. What's important is what you are going to do with those strings. Lots of random access? Searching through the list? Adding/removing elements? These questions will help you pick the proper data structure.

Comment: An `ArrayList` is special dynamic `array`.  The only thing I might suggest is you provide either a initial capacity to the construct or calling `ensureCapacity`.  This will allow the list to grow more efficiently. Basically. `ArrayList` will grow the list by one element where there is no enough space for a new element.  This ends calling `Arrays.copy` to move the contents from the old backing array to the new one, which can become inefficient (worse case, you'll have two arrays, one with 49, 999 elements and one with 50, 000 elements in memory at once...

Comment: @MadProgrammer the array is typically _doubled_ in size, so the worst case is actually 2 arrays, one with 49,999 elements and one with twice that, 99998 (though of course, the actual array sizes would be powers of 2 :)

Comment: I am building an app that gets all of the html files from a local directory and parses those html files.

Comment: @MattBall Actually (after reading through the code a bit more), it would more like 74999 ((49999 * 3) / 2 + 1) - needless to say, better to ensure a decent capacity before you start ;)

Comment: @jadrijan : what are you going to with the returned value - listOfDirectories?

Comment: @Ashwin after doing some more reading I just realized that there is a better way of walking the file tree in Java 7, using DirectoryStream and FileVisitor interfaces. Also I will use rai.skumar's suggestion to write paths to a text file, I think it is better than keeping them in memory.

Answer (score 5):

`List` is just an interface, so it really depends on the list implementation. Assuming `ArrayList<String>`, it will be roughly as memory-efficient as a `String[]`. The *worst* case for an array list is that the underlying array is a constant factor (typically 2) larger than the amount of data it's actually storing.

If you need memory efficiency, depending on how you're *using* the list later, you could use something like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: IIRC, the constant factor is actually 1.5x.  That said -- the memory usage of the `String`s themselves will almost certainly outstrip the list you're storing them in.

Comment: It is not a constant factor ... it is an average factor ... and it assumes that you didn't massively over allocate in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

An `ArrayList<String>` is close to a bare `String[]` in memory usage. If you know that you are going to store about 50,000 strings, it would help to construct the `ArrayList` with that initial capacity; it would drastically cut down on reallocations. I definitely would not use a `LinkedList`, however. That has considerably more overhead.

There will be no trouble storing 50,000 entries provided the strings themselves fit into memory.

Answer (score 2):

The list can handle it, it only depends on whether have that much of memory available or not.

If you really know that your going to have 50000 elements then it would be good to declare the list as follows

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(50000); //specify the initial capacity
```

That will eliminate the list-resizing overhead.

Comment: I think you mean "eliminate" rather than "element".  (Though you might also have meant "elephant" :-~ :-) )

Comment: Yes that's what I meant to write but I don't know how I got element there. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed; you are looking for efficient way to search your local directory for html files.

So i think there is no point storing all details in memory in ArrayList as the number of html files will keep on varying. I will suggest you should run a process which searches all those files and you store html file names in a separate physical file ( say a txt file). This way you can keep updating your list of files at regular interval by running the job ( you can have a unix script or can do even through java ).

And when you actually need to perform some operations on those html files; read html file names from your txt file.

After reading from txt file you can use ArrayList; but will not suggest to hold all names in memory.